# Make that when an image become bigger with css it does it in the front of everything

Tags: html, css

Rigth now I got an image that becomes bigger when I pass my mouse over it, but I have a navbar above the image and a graph under it, so rigth now  it gets bigger but it does it behin the navbar and the graph but I need it to do it in front of them.

Here is my code (absolutelly really easy):

html:

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="<?= ISO_ROOT . DS . $img["img_id"].$img["ext"]; ?>" alt="Isobata">
</div>
```

Css:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
}



.image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.image img {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease; /* Firefox */
    -o-transition: all 1s ease; /* IE 9 */
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease; /* Opera */
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.image:hover img {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.5); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.5); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.5); /* Opera */
     transform:scale(1.5);
}
```

Let me know if you need more information, and allthe ideas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`Z-index` controls how images or divs stack over each other. Div/image with higher `z-index` value takes front place and lower would stay behind.
Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, `position:relative`, or `position:fixed`). Use one of those.

Comment: thanks it is working except with the header, this one still in the front of the image when I make it bigger, any suggestion?

Comment: can you provide link, or jsfidle, or here complete code, it is hard to say without complete code.